# Get nested key value pair of x-www-form-urlencoded request in JSON format in golang

Tags: go, nested, x-www-form-urlencoded

I have use case where we are getting nested key value in `x-www-form-urlencoded` body like below

`name=abc&age=12&notes[key1]=value1&notes[key2]=value2`

I tried `url.ParseQuery("name=abc&age=12&notes\[key1\]=value1&notes\[key2\]=value2")` but it's giving

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "age": 12,
  "notes[key1]": "value1",
  "notes[key2]": "value2"
}
```

How can I get this value in below JSON format for above body

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "age": 12,
  "notes": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
}
```

There is possibility that notes might be in 3 level nested format

I have tried `url.ParseQuery` and `r.Form` but both of them giving `notes[key1]` and `notes[key2]`.

Comment: FYI, `url.ParseQuery()` returns a `url.Values` which is a `map[string][]string` and is marshaled to a different JSON string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To unmarshal nested key values with this type of query string parameter names, it's possible to use [`derekstavis/go-qs`](https://github.com/derekstavis/go-qs) which is a port of Rack's query string parser.

This returns a `map[string]interface{}` with nested key values as follows.

> Of note, the value for `age` is returned as a string, however, this is the same for `url.ParseQuery`. If marshaling this to an integer is desired, the package can be forked and modified.

```json
{
  "age": "12",
  "name": "abc",
  "notes": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
}
```

A complete example is available on the Go Playground with the following code:

Go Playground URL: https://go.dev/play/p/Px7uZWRNs5V

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    qs "github.com/derekstavis/go-qs"
)

func main() {
    v := "name=abc&age=12&notes[key1]=value1&notes[key2]=value2"

    q, err := qs.Unmarshal(v)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    j, err := json.MarshalIndent(q, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(j))
}
```